# Pandas DF - Group by + Sum and then Draw Lines for each Category Totals

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a DF with gas consumption data with county and time columns.

```
df[['Gas','ReportDate_Time', 'County']].head()


Gas ReportDate_Time County
0   3757.0  2017-10-01  MCK
1   2271.0  2017-10-01  MCK
2   2366.0  2017-10-01  MCK
3   1749.0  2017-10-01  MCK
4   1173.0  2017-10-01  MCK
```

I grouped by County and Date and summed the results:

```
df[['Gas','ReportDate_Time', 'County']].groupby(['ReportDate_Time', 'County']).sum().reset_index()

    ReportDate_Time County  Gas
0   2015-05-01  BIL 543126.0
1   2015-05-01  BOT 26681.0
2   2015-05-01  BOW 1028693.0
3   2015-05-01  BRK 754380.0
4   2015-05-01  DIV 1494449.0
... ... ... ...
533 2018-02-01  REN 2720.0
534 2018-02-01  SLP 6656.0
535 2018-02-01  STK 570531.0
536 2018-02-01  WIL 10085655.0
537 2018-02-01  WRD 1167.0
```

I would like to have a single plot with multiple lines, each line representing Gas across time. I have tried using the .plot() method in a few different ways but I am unable to proceed further.

Comment: Do you want to have a barplot, or a lineplot ?

Comment: Either one is ok, I think I was just supposed to use the .unstack() method but go ahead and take this one!

Comment: I think you probably want a lineplot because you are trying to produce a plot show gas trends for a county over time. Each county is going to be your line and then values will change over time. A barplot can't really do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, try:

```
df[['Gas','ReportDate_Time', 'County']].groupby(['ReportDate_Time', 'County'])\
                                       .sum()\
                                       .unstack()\
                                       .plot()
```